# Документация Django скачать

Tags: python, django, документация

Подскажите пожалуйста, где можно скачать документацию Django (желательно последней версии и на русском)? Искал, находил только очень старые или неполные версии.

Comment: https://djbook.ru/rel3.0/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Официальный сайт: `https://www.djangoproject.com`.

Русская версия: `https://djbook.ru`.

Оффлайн справочник: `https://zealdocs.org`. Тут есть и `Django`.